# Css width Child alignment

Tags: html, css

i just started learning html/css and encountered a problem which i dont really understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style>

.parenta {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color : #01DFD7; 
}

.parentb {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color : #01DFD7;
}

.child{
    background-color : #F5A9F2;
    margin-top: 2%; 
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="parenta">
            A
            <div class="child">A</div>

    </div>

    <div class="parentb">
            B
            <div class="child">B</div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Why are the child elements not aligned? If i change the width attribute of parenta and parentb to 50% it works just fine. Also, if i delete the margin-top, it also works.

Thanks

Comment: What you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use margin-top with a % in this case which by changing to px for example would fix this.

Just a tip. use px top and bottom and % for left and right.

Comment: the margin-top is on each child